# FileNotFound Error While Fetching data from Hive External Table using HiveContext

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to fetch data from a hive external table using HiveContext and storing it in a text file. The path of data for hive external table is hdfs:/data/abc/job_log. My code is failing intermittently with below error.

WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1524.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1524, ): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /data/abc/job_log/abc_job_20171027001515.*COPYING*
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1828)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1799)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:672)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)

I am using Spark 1.6.1 , Scala 2.10.5 and HDP 2.4.2 cluster.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could you please share the code snippet, that will be helpful to debug

Comment: @Sanket I am using hiveContext.sql("<query>") to fetch data and the using PrintWriter to write data to text file.

Comment: don't use printwriter. it is used to write on local filesystem, use other write APIs like saveAsTextFile for RDD and for DF, write

Comment: I have to write it to local file system that why am using printwritter here.But issue here is not with printwritter. Its failing while getting data from hive.